After Lid open, touchpad is not enabled Ubuntu 22.04 and Budgie on my Lenovo Flex 5
I have been struggling with this annoying problem for long time and none of the suggestions on the forum and search haven't solved it. I'd appreciate any help that can lead me to the solution.
I can enable/disable it via xinput but it doesn't work before I manually enable in the Touchpad graphical setting in Budgie. Very annoying
Reproducing the problem:

Use touchpad as normal -> All ok
Close Lid
Wait 5 secs
Open Lid.

I see graphical notifications on Lid disables and the enabled. However, the touchpad still doesn't work and I have to go into graphical settings and enable it using my keyboard manually.
Any help would be appreiciated.
System configuration:
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN06FA:00 04F3:3140 Mouse               id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN06FA:00 04F3:3140 Touchpad            id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 5216 Finger                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Wacom HID 5216 Pen                        id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]

/proc/bus/input/devices
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event2 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=a0000702100000 83803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=056a Product=5216 Version=0100
N: Name="Wacom HID 5216 Pen"
P: Phys=i2c-WACF2200:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-WACF2200:00/0018:056A:5216.0002/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event5 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=1c03 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=1000d000003
B: MSC=1

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=056a Product=5216 Version=0100
N: Name="Wacom HID 5216 Finger"
P: Phys=i2c-WACF2200:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-WACF2200:00/0018:056A:5216.0002/input/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse3 event6 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003
B: MSC=20

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Ideapad extra buttons"
P: Phys=ideapad/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=400000000000000 0 0 6000800000000000 100000000000 0 81000800100c03 4400000000300400 0 2
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Lenovo Yoga Tablet Mode Control switch"
P: Phys=06129D99-6083-4164-81AD-F092F9D773A6/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/PNP0C14:05/wmi_bus/wmi_bus-PNP0C14:05/06129D99-6083-4164-81AD-F092F9D773A6/input/input16
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=2

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=3140 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN06FA:00 04F3:3140 Mouse"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN06FA:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN06FA:00/0018:04F3:3140.0001/input/input17
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=30000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=1943
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=3140 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN06FA:00 04F3:3140 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN06FA:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN06FA:00/0018:04F3:3140.0001/input/input18
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event8 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input19
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input20
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input21
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input22
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input23
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event13 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input24
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event14 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

